# Laravel top level Application instance in Facade class

Tags: php, laravel

In Laravel facade class there is the following static method.

```php
public static function setFacadeApplication($app)
{
    static::$app = $app;   
}
```

Which sets the Laravel application instance as the Facade class static property, so that facades can be resolved out of the IoC container. Facade class has access to application instance through this method but how? 
I can't find where this method above is called.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. My vim ctags couldn't find but it is called from

```
Illuminate\Foundation\start.php on line 93.
```